# Error when trying to uv unwrap

Tags: uv, error

when I'm trying to unwrap, Blender gives an error back and the unwraped uv looks strange. See image below... I researched for this topic bud can't find anything. Maybe one of you know this issue.

The error massage is: Unwrap failed to solve 1 of 1 island(s), edge seams may need to be added

Error occurs with the default cube and every other mesh.

Blender 2.93.0 (no additional plugins)
Win10 Pro
Nvidia Quadro K4200 (newest driver)

I tryed to:

1. find any settings that cause the error
2. uninstall and install Blender
3. repair the installation of Blender

Thanks for your help!

[image: strange uv unwrap]